# Regex for Parsing vertical CSV in Athena

Tags: regex, hive, amazon-athena

So, I've been trying to load csvs from a s3 bucket into Athena. However, the way the csv are designer looks like the following

```
ns=2;s=A_EREG.A_EREG.A_PHASE_PRESSURE,102.19468,12/12/19 00:00:01.2144275 GMT
ns=2;s=A_EREG.A_EREG.A_PHASE_REF_SIGNAL_TO_VALVE,50.0,12/12/19 00:00:01.2144275 GMT
ns=2;s=A_EREG.A_EREG.A_PHASE_SEC_CURRENT,15.919731,12/12/19 00:00:01.2144275 GMT
ns=2;s=A_EREG.A_EREG.A_PHASE_SEC_VOLTAGE,0.22070877,12/12/19 00:00:01.2144275 GMT
ns=2;s=A_EREG.A_EREG.ACTIVE_PWR,0.0,12/12/19 00:00:01.2144275 GMT
```

The csv is just one record. Each column of the record has a value associated to it, which sits between two commas between the timestamp and the name, which I am trying to capture.
I've been trying to parse it using Regex Serde and I got to this Regular expression:

```
((?<=\,).*?(?=\,))
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/HnjnxK/1)
I want the output of the above to be:

```
col_a       col_b    col_c      col_d          col_e 
102.19468   50.0     15.919731  0.22070877     0.0
```

My DDL query looks like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
(...)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1',
  'input.regex' = "\(?<=\,).*?(?=\,)"
) LOCATION 's3://jackson-nifi-plc-data-1/2019-12-12/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

The table creation Query above works succesfully, but when I try to preview my table I get the following error:

```
HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: Number of matching groups doesn't match the number of columns
```

I am fairly new to Hive and Regex so I don't know what is going on. Can someone help me out here?

Thanks in advance,
BR

Comment: Don't know about the regex flavour/behaviour in Athena but you want to match a comma, something then another comma - but ignore the commas in your result. Try non-capturing groups: `(?:,).*?(?:,)`

Answer (score 0):

One column in Hive table corresponds to one capturing group in the regex. If you want to select single column containing everything between commas then this will work:

```
'.*,(.*),.*'
```

Comment: Hey. I think you almost got it. the problem is, each value between commas should correspond to one column. Therefore, since I declared multiple columns when creating the table I am still getting the same error. I think we need to have multiple capturing groups, one for each value...

Comment: @Luiz_F It is not clear. Could you please provide expected output based on the data example you already posted

Comment: I added the expected output to the post.

Comment: @Luiz_F okay. Are you saying that all those rows in the data example is actually single row in the text file? Or thiose are different rows? Also can you anchor to the specific names instead of positions? i mean A_PHASE_PRESSURE,<value>,

Comment: Yes. They are a single row. I tried anchoring to the specific names. The query runs and creates the tables. I try to preview it and it did not give me the error of non-matching number of columnst this time! However, it is giving me blank rows when I preview the table. I should probably open another question for this other issue, but do you have any ideas in mind as to why it is giving me blank results ? Thanks so much

Comment: @Luiz_F AFAIK regexserde works like this: one capturing group per column., similar to this (extracting second column): `select regexp_extract(str,'^[^,]*?A_PHASE_PRESSURE,([0-9.]+?),[^,]*?A_PHASE_REF_SIGNAL_TO_VALVE,([0-9.]+?),',2) from ...`

Comment: @Luiz_F Maybe the problem is multiline content

Answer (score 0):

Athena serdes require that each record in the input is a single line. Multiline records are not supported.

What you can do instead is to create a table which maps each line in your data to a row in a table, and use a view to pivot the rows that belong together into a single row.

I'm going to assume that the `ns` field at the start of the lines is an ID, if not, I assume there is some other thing identifying which lines belong together that you can use.

I used your demo to create a regex that matched all the fields of each line and came up with `ns=(\d);s=([^,]+),([^,]+),(.+)` (see https://regex101.com/r/HnjnxK/5).

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_data (
  ns string,
  s string,
  v double,
  dt string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1',
  'input.regex' = "ns=(\\d);s=([^,]+),([^,]+),(.+)"
)
LOCATION 's3://jackson-nifi-plc-data-1/2019-12-12/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false')
```

Apologies if the regex isn't correctly escaped, I'm just typing this into Stack Overflow.

This table has four columns, corresponding to the four fields in each line. I've named then `ns` and `s` from the data, and `v` for the numerical value, and `dt` for the date. The date needs to be typed as a string since it's not in a format Athena natively understands.

Assuming that `ns` is a record identifier you can then create a view that pivots rows with different values for `s` to columns. You have to do this the way you want it to, the following is of course just a demonstration:

```
CREATE VIEW my_pivoted_data AS
WITH data_aggregated_by_ns AS (
  SELECT
    ns,
    map_agg(array_agg(s), array_agg(v)) AS s_and_v
  FROM my_data
  GROUP BY ns
)
SELECT
  ns,
  element_at(s_and_v, 'A_EREG.A_EREG.A_PHASE_PRESSURE') AS phase_pressure,
  element_at(s_and_v, 'A_EREG.A_EREG.A_PHASE_REF_SIGNAL_TO_VALVE') AS phase_ref_signal_to_valve,
  element_at(s_and_v, 'A_EREG.A_EREG.A_PHASE_SEC_CURRENT') AS phase_sec_current,
  element_at(s_and_v, 'A_EREG.A_EREG.A_PHASE_SEC_VOLTAGE') AS phase_sec_voltage,
  element_at(s_and_v, 'A_EREG.A_EREG.ACTIVE_PWR') AS active_pwr
FROM data_aggregated_by_ns
```

Apologies if there are syntax errors in the SQL above.

What this does is that it creates a view (but start by trying it out as a query using everything from `WITH` and onwards), which has two parts to it.

The first part, the first `SELECT` results in rows that aggregate all the `s` and `v` values for each value of `ns` into a map. Try to run this query by itself to see how the result looks.

The second part, the second `SELECT` uses the results of the first part and just picks out the different `v` values for a number of values of `s` that I chose from your question using the aggregated map.